Internal DNS not working unless I use googles open dns
I am thinking an error when step upgrading from 16 to 22.04, but it JUST started happening. etc/netplan is completely empty there are no config files in it at all. I really do not want to wipe and reinstall 22.04 mainly because its remote, and it will take ages to backup 800+gigs of data, plus all my other settings.
Everything coming in(website access) works fine no issues.
ssh, takes forever to connect(about 2 minutes, using domain name, instantly with ip)
The kicker, anything else does not work, without me adding googles open DNS to resovleconf. When I say everything I mean connecting to any repository for updates
can't connect to minecrafts auth server for logins.
If I manually use wget to download a file(if i know the IP location it works fine).
results of resolvectl status
    Global

Protocols: -LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported

resolv.conf mode: foreign

Current DNS Server: 8.8.8.8

DNS Servers: 8.8.8.8 127.0.0.1

Link 2 (eth0)

Current Scopes: none

Protocols: -DefaultRoute +LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported

Link 3 (docker0)

Current Scopes: none

Protocols: -DefaultRoute +LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported

resolveconf:
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)

# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN

# 127.0.0.53 is the systemd-resolved stub resolver.

# run "systemd-resolve --status" to see details about the actual nameservers.

nameserver 127.0.0.53

nameserver 8.8.8.8

netplan status:
 Online state: offline
    DNS Addresses: 127.0.0.53
                   8.8.8.8
                   8.8.4.4

●  1: lo ethernet UNKNOWN/UP (unmanaged)
      MAC Address: 00:00:00:00:00:00
        Addresses: 127.0.0.1/8

●  2: eth0 ethernet UP (unmanaged)
      MAC Address: 44:8a:5b:95:cb:ac (Intel Corporation)
        Addresses: 74.208.12.147/32
                   74.208.12.191/32
           Routes: default via 10.255.255.1 (boot)
                   10.255.255.1 from 74.208.12.147 (link)

networkctl list:
IDX LINK    TYPE     OPERATIONAL SETUP
  1 lo      loopback carrier     unmanaged
  2 eth0    ether    routable    unmanaged
  3 docker0 bridge   no-carrier  unmanaged

Interfaces:
/etc/network/interfaces -- configuration file for ifup(8), ifdown(8)

# Generated by debian-installer.

# The loopback interface

auto eth0

iface eth0 inet static

address iphere

netmask 255.255.255.255

gateway 10.255.255.1

pointopoint 10.255.255.1

auto eth0:1

allow-hotplug eth0:1

iface eth0:1 inet static

address iphere/32

allow-hotplug eth0

iface eth0 inet6 static

address stupidip6here

netmask 64

post-up ip -6 route add fe80::1 dev eth0

post-up ip -6 route add default via fe80::1 dev eth0

post-down ip -6 route del default via fe80::1 dev eth0

post-down ip -6 route del fe80::1 dev eth0

any help or insight would be appreciated.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

From what you posted, I guess DNS resolution is managed by systemd-resolved, in which case you should not edit /etc/resolv.conf manually. It seems systemd-networkd isn’t managing your internet connection either… so I suppose it’s either NetworkManager, or ifupdown, more likely the latter from what you posted. To put that out of the way, can you post the output of nmcli device ? Can you post the output of ls -l /etc/resolv.conf as well ?
